# Count how many time a value is similair on a special key

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the number of element who are similar in an array, I have this type of array :

```
const array = [['test', true], ['test', false], ['test', true], ['test2', true], ...
```

And I want to get an array prototyped like this :

```
[the key, nbr of duplicates of this key, nbr of true, nbr of false]
```

Sorry for my poor english, this is a bit complex to explains, I hope you understood

Comment: Keep a second array of key references: var keys = []
Start iterating your array, check if you already counted the current key by look in the "keys" array, if no push it there and start counting references ( you can even remove them to don't check ).

Answer (score 1):

You could e.g. do it like this:

```js
const array = [['test', true], ['test', false], ['test', true], ['test2', true]];

const result = {};
array.forEach(item => {
  const key = item[0];
  const value = item[1];
  if(!result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    result[key] = {
      key: key,
      active: 0,
      inactive: 0
    };
  }
  if (value) {
    result[key].active++;
  } else {
    result[key].inactive++;
  }
});

console.log('The result as an object:');
console.log(result);
console.log('---');
console.log('The result as an array:');
console.log(Object.keys(result).map(item => result[item]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an empty object for counting the values.

```js
var data = [['test', true], ['test', false], ['test', true], ['test2', true]],
    result = data.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        r[k] = r[k] || {};
        r[k][v] = (r[k][v] || 0) + 1;
        return r
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I will use this method :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method to create an object and then use `Object.values` to get an array of values.

```js
const array = [['test', true], ['test', false], ['test', true], ['test2', true]]
const result = array.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  if(!r[k]) r[k] = [k, 0, 0, 0];
  r[k][(v ? 2 : 3)]++
  r[k][1]++;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```